# How to calculate the intrinsic drain voltage (Vk)?

Tags: high-voltage

How to calculate the intrinsic drain voltage (Vk) using TCAD results.

I didn't find a good explanation online, only compact models that doesn't help in TCAD simulation.

I want to plot Vk, which depends on the drain and gate voltages, as shown in the attached image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/33585

Comment: So, do I just have to declare a new contact at the the physical metallurgical junction between the p-body/n-tub regions ?!